# GitLab: How to find the owner of an SSH key

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

Given an SSH public key or fingerprint that has been registered with GitLab, how do I find out which account is associated with that key?

Note that the key may have been registered as a "deploy key," in which case I'd like to know account that registered it.

I'd prefer to know ways to do this using both the standard web UI (if possible), and programatically via the REST API. If neither of these are possible, I'll take answers that involve digging into the internals of GitLab (e.g., via a query on GitLab's database) if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GitLab 12.6 the [Keys API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/keys.html) introduced a method to [get a user by SSH key fingerprint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/keys.html#get-user-by-fingerprint-of-ssh-key).

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/keys?fingerprint=01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef:01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef"
```

If the key happens to be a deploy key, in GitLab 12.7 the same `keys` endpoint was enhanced to [get a user by deploy key fingerprint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/keys.html#get-user-by-deploy-key-fingerprint) as well.

Note that both of these methods are only available to GitLab adminstrators.

Answer (score 10):

If you can access the postgres console:

```
root@gitlab:/# gitlab-psql
    psql (9.6.8)
    Type "help" for help.

    gitlabhq_production=#
    gitlabhq_production=# select a.name,a.username,b.fingerprint 
from users a, keys b where a.id=b.user_id;

         name      | username |                   fingerprint                   
    ---------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------
     Administrator | root     | f4:cc:ec:76:d0:1c:86:1d:45:6d:a7:6e:b3:df:32:7c
    (1 row)
```

Comment: This is marked accepted since it's the best solution so far, but I'm open to accepting easier solutions if there are any. (It sounds like there are not.)

Comment: `select a.name,a.username,b.key from users a, keys b where a.id=b.user_id and b.key like '%your_key%';`

Answer (score 8):

With a GitLab omnibus installation, you can use the rails console:

```
gitlab-rails console
> User.find(Key.find_by(fingerprint: '00:00:00:00...').user_id)
```

With the value of fingerprint being replaced with the md5 fingerprint of the key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any public API (like in the [User API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html) for instance) which would take an SSH key fingerprint as a parameter.

I see it used only as an *internal* API, to retrieve the actual SSH key: [merge request 250](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/250).

[That code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/commit/81258588d155a6289795f749af28cbd9c015e537) can give you a clue to as to how to code your own search.